# Issue with delete multiple orders - codeigniter 3

Tags: javascript, codeigniter-3

With this function I can correct delete single record:

```
`    //delete order
    public function delete_order($id)
    {
        $id = clean_number($id);
        $order = $this->get_order($id);
        if (!empty($order)) {
            //delete order products
            $order_products = $this->get_order_products($id);
            if (!empty($order_products)) {
                foreach ($order_products as $order_product) {
                    $this->db->where('id', $order_product->id);
                    $this->db->delete('order_products');
                }
            }
            //delete invoice
            $this->db->where('order_id', $order->id)->delete('invoices');
            //delete order
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            return $this->db->delete('orders');
        }
        return false;
    }`
```

Now I try prepare function for delete multiple records.

In header table I add:

```
` <th scope="col" style="width: 25px;">
                                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                              <input class="form-check-input fs-15" type="checkbox" id="checkAll">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </th>`
```

and in foreach:

```
      ` <th scope="row">
                                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                                <input class="form-check-input fs-15" name="checkbox-table" type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="<?php echo $item->id; ?>">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </th>`
```

Now I created action:

```
`<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="delete_selected_orders('<?php echo trans("confirm_products"); ?>');"><?php echo trans('delete'); ?></a>`
```

.js script

```
`<script>
//delete selected orders
function delete_selected_orders(message) {
    swal({
        text: message,
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        buttons: [sweetalert_cancel, sweetalert_ok],
        dangerMode: true,
    }).then(function (willDelete) {
        if (willDelete) {
            var order_ids = [];
            $("input[name='checkbox-table']:checked").each(function () {
                order_ids.push(this.value);
            });
            var data = {
                'order_ids': order_ids,
            };
            data[csfr_token_name] = $.cookie(csfr_cookie_name);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: base_url + "order_admin_controller/delete_selected_orders",
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
</script>`
```

order_admin_controller/delete_selected_orders

```
`    /**
     * Delete Selected Orders
     */
    public function delete_selected_orders()
    {
        $order_ids = $this->input->post('order_ids', true);
        $this->order_admin_model->delete_multi_orders($order_ids);

        //reset cache
        reset_cache_data_on_change();
    }`
```

model

```
    //delete multi order
    public function delete_multi_orders($order_ids)
    {
        if (!empty($order_ids)) {
            foreach ($order_ids as $id) {
                $this->delete_order($id);
            }
        }
    }`
```

When I check all and post delete multiple action then I see sweatalert to confirm delete, when I confirm I not see any error in console browser. But When I select multiple records and post then page refresh and  orders not deleted.

I think function `controller/model` is correct. But im not sure with this in `.js` order_ids  and in view table if I  post `order_ids` correct.